# Why can't I see ngOnChanges logged in my application

Tags: angular, lifecycle

I am new to Angular and am trying to get a hold of life cycle hooks. However, I am confused because what I see in my code doesn't go along with the documentation.

I have following code in my component class:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit", this.personList);
    this.person = this.pService.getName();
}

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("ngOnChanges", this.personList, arguments);
}

ngDoCheck() {
    console.log("ngDoCheck", this.personList, arguments);
}

ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("ngAfterContentInit", this.personList, arguments);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit", this.personList, arguments);
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log("ngAfterViewChecked", this.personList, arguments);
}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
    console.log("ngAfterContentChecked", this.personList, arguments);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("ngOnDestroy", this.personList, arguments);
}

changeclr() {
        this.person = this.name === 'Saurabh' ? 'Navanshu' : 'Saurabh';
}
```

The [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) here says `ngOnchanges` gets triggered before `ngonInit` but I can't see any logs for `ngOnChanges` while application loads.

The docs also says `ngOnChnages` runs while data-bound property changes. Is it specific to properties set using `@Input`, because I can't see any logs while I change `this.person` using my `changclr` method.

Am I getting something wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

**ngOnChanges** will fire only when you have **@Input()** parameter in your class/component, it will executed when any input parameter value is updated.

In your code you haven't mension any thing about input parameter and hence your ngOnChanges not logged.

may be you have to define like : @Input() person :any;